# Sympy.solve is not isolating desired variable in inequality

Tags: sympy, inequality

I want to use nypy.solve to convert a formular to a certain variable. In my example I want to convert the formular a >= ((b-c)/2)*sy.tan(d) to the variable b. But somehow the result of Sympy is not converted to b.

This is my Code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sympy as sy
a = sy.symbols('a')
b = sy.symbols('b')
c = sy.symbols('c')
d = sy.symbols('d')

eq = sy.Ge(a, ((b-c)/2)*sy.tan(d))
result = sy.solve(eq, 'b')
print(result)
```

The output is this:

```
-b*tan(d)/2 >= -a - c*tan(d)/2
```

what i want to get is:

```
b >= (2*a+c*tan(d))/tan(d)
```

How do I use sympy correctly to get this?

Answer (score 1):

SymPy won't divide by a factor of an unknown sign when trying to solve an inequality. So use a signed symbol for `tan(d)`, e.g. `Dummy(positive=True)` or `Dummy(negative=True)` and put your results in `Piecewise((results_pos, (tan(d)>0)),(result_neg, tan(d)<0))`:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> f = lambda x: solve(eq.subs(tan(d),x),'b').subs(x,tan(d))
>>> p,n=Dummy(positive=True),Dummy(negative=True)
>>> Piecewise((f(p), tan(d)>0),(f(n), tan(d)<0))
Piecewise((b < -2*(-a - c*tan(d)/2)/tan(d), tan(d) > 0),
          (b > -2*(-a - c*tan(d)/2)/tan(d), tan(d) < 0))
```

If you are solving linear inequalities, you can just re-arrange the equation by hand instead of using `solve`:

```py
def solve_ineq(eq, sym):
    i, d = (eq.lhs - eq.rhs).expand().as_independent(sym, as_Add=True)
    m = d.coeff(sym)
    lr = (sym, -i/m)
    return Piecewise((eq.func(*lr), m>0),(eq.reversed.func(*lr), m<0))


>>> from sympy.abc import y
>>> solve_ineq(x*y>=2-x, x)
Piecewise((x >= 2/(y + 1), y > -1), (x <= 2/(y + 1), y < -1))
```

I highly recommend that you use `Piecewise` so you don't lose track of what it was that you need to assume is positive. In the example I gave, the value of `y` could be `-1/2` and the pertinent coefficient of `x` would still be positive.

{note use of `from sympy import *` at the start which imports all the needed object for this example.}

Comment: Hi, thank your for your help! 
When I try to use your code I get an Error saying "name 'Dummy' is not defined" and "name 'Piecewise' is not defined". What do I haave to do to make your Code work?

Comment: Additionally: if I try this with d instead of tan(d) in the formular: a >= ((b-c)/2)*d then I get the same Problem. The result is 'd*(-b + c)/2 >= -a'. And I need this Code to work with any Variable Names and equations. Is there a way to make this work? An assumption that works for me would be to always say that the part that could get negative never gets negative, but i dont know how to implement this without knowing what the equation looks like beforehand.

Comment: The answer was updated.

Comment: Hi, your code works very well for "normal" inequations. Thank you very much so far!
But there is still a problem: If I use my example (with tan(d)) and try to solve it for d, than the result is nan. Can I do something to make this work with trigonometric functions?

Comment: Same thing with exponential functions. It doesnt solve something with for example 2**d for d

Comment: The nonlinear case is left as an exercise for the reader. Consider solving for the zeros of the equality `Eq(*ineq.args)`.

Comment: I dont understand what exactly this does and how to implement this. Can you help me with that? I want this to work with equations with multiple variables and with all kinds of mathematical functions like quadratic functions, trigonometric functions, exponentiell functions, logarithmic functions, fractures and so on.
another equation that doesnt get solved correctly is 'a/b<=c' and I dont get why.

Comment: How would you solve `-x**2 + 5 > 4` or `-x**2 + 5 < 4`, or x**3 - 4*x**2+3 > 1?

Comment: if I use the code from my inital post, then the result is   
(-1 <= x) & (x <= 1)   
and since in my application variables cannot take negative values, I could write a code that searches for '-' and takes the other answer. Alternatively I could define x as follows:   
x = sy.symbols('x', positive=True)   
Then  I get only the positive answer. The problem is, if I try this with multiple variables, then I get an Error:   
NotImplementedError:   
inequality has more than one symbol of interest.

Comment: You need a better problem scope. The general case is going to potentially be very unruly. Consider `eq=(x - a)*(x - b)` that has roots for `x` and `a` and `b`. There are three relationships that could hold for `a` and `b`, dividing the number line into 2 or 3 sections. Expressing where `eq > 0` will look like `Piecewise((And(x<a,x>b),a<b),(And(x<b,x>a),(a>b)),(Ne(x,a),True))`.